# Creating an Android virtual device with Genymotion - Android

Tags: android, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I gave up using `Android Studio` to start my custom `.avd` Android image via `Android Virtual Device Manager` (it was taking more than 30 min).
Now I'm trying to import `Bradley.avd` (along with `Bradley.ini`) in `Genymotion`. However, when I click `Add+` I don't have a way to import my `.avd`. How can I import / use `.avd` into `Genymotion`? [image][image]

I've added the two screen shots for clarification in what I'm trying to do. I also have `Virtualbox` installed.

Answer (score 1):

You can't - Genemotion and "Android virtual device" is not connected at all (afaik first is x86 second is translation of ARM to X86). Follow [genymotion user guide](https://www.genymotion.com/#!/developers/user-guide) please.

[image]

Select a virtual device from the list and click Next.

[image]

Enter a name for your new virtual device and click Next.