# Error while waiting for device: Could not start AVD. Can I skip enabling VT-x BIOS and HAXM?

Tags: android

I am newbie to Android and Gradle. I have checked out source code from https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader. Also I have installed all latest versions of Android studio and gradle just today. Since the gradle version requires build tools version as 26.0.2 I have commented the line

```
//buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
```

so that it takes now version 26.0.2 and earlier encountered error- "Failed to find Build Tools revision 26.0.2" is gone.

I created AVD in android studio and tried running sample app from above github repository and it's suggesting to Enable VT-x BIOS. I do not know why VT-x BIOS is required or why Intel HAXM is required. I do not know whether enabling VT-x BIOS or installing HAXM would harm my computer. Hence I did not enable VT-x BIOS and not installed HAXM yet.

Can anyone guide me to get rid of below error where no other meaningful trace is shown on gradle console as you can see in the attachment.

Error while waiting for device: Could not start AVD

Attached both screenshots displaying the AVD and the error. Is there any way without enabling the VT-x BIOS or Intel HAXM. Can this step be skipped and will I be able to run this sample app? I want to keep this as the last alternative of enabling BIOS or HAXM. Has anyone tried running this sample app?

```
[![enter image description here][2]][2]
[![enter image description here][3]][3]
[![enter image description here][4]][4]
[![enter image description here][5]][5]
```

Comment: You need to enable VT-x it will not harm your computer :). And if you don't want to do it you can use GenyMotion emulators or real devices.

Comment: Could not upload the screen-shot of error in gradle console because image size is bigger. But I have that checked no meaningful trace is shown over there.

Comment: have you enabled it through your bios ?.

Comment: @Umair-what is VT-x? Does this depend on what an app needs to do or is this a general thing for all android apps? Can you share link to install GenyMotion?

Comment: Check my answer. You will get the idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intel Virtualization Technology (VT). Formerly known as Vanderpool, this technology enables a CPU to act as if you have several independent computers, in order to enable several operating systems to run at the same time on the same machine. In this tutorial we will explain everything you need to know about this technology. Intel’s virtualization technology is available in two versions: VT-x, for x86 processors; and VT-i, for Itanium (i.e., IA-64) processors.

If you want to read more please take a look at this answer.
https://superuser.com/questions/939340/what-is-vt-x-why-it-is-not-enabled-in-few-machine-by-default

And if you want to enable it then refer to this 
[Enable VT-x in your BIOS security settings (refer to documentation for your computer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39542853/enable-vt-x-in-your-bios-security-settings-refer-to-documentation-for-your-comp)

And if you don't want to activate VTx go to this link and install **genymotion**. Also I believe you will need to install virutal machine too to run these emulators 
[GenyMotion](https://www.genymotion.com/)

Comment: do I need to download genymotion with virtual box or without virtual box?

Comment: @Prakash if you already have a virtual box then no, otherwise yes :)

Comment: @Prakash basically virtual box is VM on which your emulator will run.

Comment: I have installed genymotion with virtual box. Can you tell me how to create android virtual device using genymotion?

Comment: @Prakash go through these links it will help you what you want to achieve:

https://docs.genymotion.com/Content/02_Application/Adding_a_new_virtual_device/Adding%20a%20new_virtual_device.htm

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30428683/creating-an-android-virtual-device-with-genymotion-android

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y2_OjsfISG8

Comment: The video u shared is for plugin into eclipse and not for Android studio. Also I m confused of what document to follow for installation. I am trying to follow Plugin-for-Android-Studio and using JetBrains repository method. Stuck here. Don't know what to do next?

Comment: @Prakash sorry i didn't noticed that. It's easy to add a plugin to android studio. Follow these links and you will be able to run it I am sure. Or just tell me where you are stucked at, ?
http://tleyden.github.io/blog/2013/11/22/android-studio-plus-genymotion-emulator/

https://www.genymotion.com/plugins/

Comment: I wanted to upload screenshot but don't know how to upload in comments

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162964/discussion-between-umair-and-prakash).

Comment: Will you be available to chat again? I am stuck at that point.

Comment: @Prakash I don't know where you are stuck at. everything is quite clear and easy to understand. :)

Comment: to start virtual device of genymotion, does this require a license? I have downloaded trial version which said to be free for 30 days

Comment: @Prakash You do not need a license to run Genymotion for personal use. Paid license is only required for commercial use (earning money with the help of Genymotion). I believe you have selected the wrong option while creating your account on genyMotion.

Comment: what company and usage type I should select for person use?

Comment: @Prakash for company = "Gamer/Personal" and for usageType = "training" or "development"

Comment: thanks Umair. Hopefully this should solve my purpose.

Comment: @Prakash if my answer helped you please accept and upvote it and if you are still having some problem feel free to tell me :)

Comment: I have already upvoted. Let me check by creating new virtual device with genymotion. I will not forget to accept the answer.

Comment: I have accepted the answer as I am able to configure genymotion in android studio. But after this I am facing some problems related to build. I don't know whether it will be appropriate to add the description of error here in comment. i.e. Posting that as separate question. Could you help me with that also if you are ok?

Comment: @Prakash you need to post a different question for that because that problem has nothing to do with genymotion. And I am glad that i could be of help. Happy Coding :)